# Attempting to wrap text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to prepare a form in excel to be completed by others. The responses will require several lines.  I've tried to merge cells and wrap text.  Then when I begin to type, the text begins at the bottom of the cell as opposed to the top.  Is there a way to have text start at the top?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2007 or later, go to Home > Alignment > Top Alignment.  Please see below illustration:

[image: Excel alignment buttons]